# Android Apk Size Investigation

Tags: android, kotlin, apk, size, reduce

I build the Apk of my Android app, which is around 177 MB. I'm already using pro-groud to reduce the app size but still, it's 177 MB what are the other methods that I can use to reduce my app size?

I have tried to use pro-gourd in my other modules.

Comment: can you please share your build gradle to show us all the deps?? and your pro-guard file for all the rules??

Comment: Use Android Studio APK analyzer to see what files inside the APK have what size. Most likely you are including large native libraries (.so) files for multiple CPU architectures (some of them irrelevant).

Comment: Apk file is a zip file. Simply unpack it and see what does take so much space. I doubt it will be the code. Most probably resources like images, etc. and maybe native libs.